# Getting eBay Access token

Tags: rest, delphi, ebay-api

**Having problem getting eBay access token using Delphi.**

When I run it and click on button I should get access token but I'm getting

> Exception EHTTPProtocolException 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'

When I click continue. Message dialog appears with meessege

> {"error":"invalid_client", "error_description":"client authentication
>   failed"}

My Delphi code:

```
procedure TForm5.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 vClientId, vClientSecret : string;
 vBase64 : String;
 vRuNames : string;
begin
  vClientId:='jackjump-xxxx-SBX-15d7a0307-68d66d5a';
  vClientSecret:='SBX-5d7a03073f13-cb20-4a72-b71e-4e53';
  vBase64:=TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(vClientId+':'+vClientSecret);
  vRuNames:='jack_jumping-jackjump-xxxx--tbccomu';

  RESTRequest1.Method:=rmPOST;
  RESTRequest1.Resource:='/identity/v1/oauth2/token';    
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Authorization', 'Basic '+vBase64, pkHTTPHEADER);
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('grant_type','client_credentials', pkREQUESTBODY);
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('redirect_uri',vRuNames, pkREQUESTBODY);
  RESTRequest1.AddParameter('scope','https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope', pkREQUESTBODY);


  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  ShowMessage(RESTResponse1.Content);
end;
```

Comment: I hope these aren't your actual credentials, if so, do yourself a favour and remove them. The mod-flag to get the edit history purged, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or

Comment: Its not ral cred. and if they are, what? it is ebay sendbox account...

Comment: Why do you need to Base64 encode the clientid and clientsecret? Also, what's the request URL? It'd save others having to look for it.

Comment: URL is set in rest client component by propetry baseURL (https://api.sandbox.ebay.com) and here im adding resurce in code...
So, url is base url + resurce, and im using base 64 beceause this example/tutorial show/tell to do that...